# Two iterators at a time in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator

I need to iterate over lines in a file and over a database object at the same time.
Seperately, I can do this using file.each_line and Object.all.each. How to combine these two? I believe I would need them both to use each only to make use of zip thing... They are of the same size.

Comment: what is the problem with `#zip` method ?

Comment: One thing uses .each_line and the second .each

Comment: Do `File.foreach('your/file').zip(database_object) { |a,b| #work here }`

Answer (score 3):

`file.each_line.zip(Object.all)` works on my computer.